# Strongly typed dataset Playing up big time

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procdure that works fine when i execute in sql server management console but when use in strongly typed dataset it always return "1" (i think that it means record is inserted).

Here's the SP

```
USE [DataBaseName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE procedure [dbo].[InsertRecord]
(
    @a int,
    @b int
)
AS

INSERT Into tableName 
Values
(
    @a,
    @b
)
return SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Now when i drag and drop the procedure on strongly typed dataset it gives me these options, before it was on "single value".

[image]

Comment: **Strongly typed dataset Playing up big time**, I like this title :)

Comment: Did the below solve the issue?

Comment: Yup, I recreated Data-set and also used OUTPUT parameter in stored procedure and catching it back in dataSet, also changed query property to SCalar from non-Execute

Comment: if you update your answer with it, I will accept it

Answer (score 1):

It might be that it's returning 1 for the inserted record due to not having `SET NOCOUNT ON;` in the SP.  Try adding this, it should solve the issue.  Not having this will give you the amount of affected records, 1 in your case.

```
USE [DataBaseName]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE procedure [dbo].[InsertRecord]
(
    @a int,
    @b int
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT Into tableName 
Values
(
    @a,
    @b
)
return SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```